# How welcoming are our communities?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

As SE grows, lots of communities grow using it. Why not? So far, so good.

As SE grows, lots of people find answers for their problems just being forwarded here by different search engines. Halleluja.

As they get more and more solutions here, they want to reciprocate and give answers. Or they want to get help here by asking questions. And then they face moderation, close requests, migrations and alike.

Let me introduce you [karakol](https://stackexchange.com/users/3799421/karakol?tab=activity), a user I kept an eye on for a week. He asked a question, thanked for all replies, stayed humble and helpful in his replies. He still could not grasp the differences between stackoverflow.com, programming.stackexchange.com and superuser.com. He could not keep up with our rules and did rage quit.

Finally my question after this long prologue:

**How could we be more welcoming?** How could we ease the learning curve? Is there really such a big gap between discussing issues through code (stackoverflow) or concepts and design (programming)? Is it a bigger difference than say the [c#] and the [java] tags? Am I the minority who has to jump between communities back and forth to ask and answer questions?

Probably there is no clear answer to this, but I hope I made a difference just by you - my reader - reading this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239141/recover-a-windows-partition-under-grub-and-lost-files suggests not grasping the difference between Stack Overflow and Super User

Comment: In some cases there is a thin difference between correctly configuring an application and scripting one.

Comment: Reinstalling an OS is not a programming question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167452/what-are-the-beans http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223979/how-to-steer-cattle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189301/make-community-movie http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225204/molly-coddle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27825/silver-spooning http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/pillows-everywhere http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242490/wear-clothes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87695/eyes-be-burning

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138657/why-kamahl http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263833/help-the-elderly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99116/on-closing-olive-garden http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172970/exempt-new-users-from-reading

Comment: Well, I guess I have something to read for the rest of the day. Thanks. I hope I can get the answers from all those links.

Comment: @random another one worth mentioning: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256003/839601)

Comment: Thanks guys for the useful links in the comments. It must be hard to face these questions over and over again. Humans needs to fixed. Oh, wait, I am human, too.

Comment: "*Funny, random, how you could decide alone that the answers to that question do apply to this one, too. This is the kind of arrogance I am talking about.*" Where...how..what? How on Earth was Random being funny to you? they commented and made a valid point. Remember, comments are short and fast, and don't have the time or space for niceties. Just to the point. "Arrogant" is just they way *you* read the comment.

Comment: That user had not read the Stack Overflow tour page (no Informed badge), he was off topic - called on it (as anyone would) - got downvotes (fully legitimate) and the question closed as off topic (as it should) - his response was to rage quit over fake internet points and still not refer to the help pages - no great loss

Comment: I just tried to pick a specific "instance", but it is just a good example that it is quite involving to start contributing to the site. The "elite club" feeling others are talking about seems to apply.

Comment: *Remember, comments are short and fast, and don't have the time or space for niceties* That is exactly my point. The SO community is rude and cares more about the rules than the attitude. And I was surprised reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256003/839601 that it was a design goal that was slightly ruined in summer 2012.

Comment: @wigy random can close your post without anyone else's help because he's an experienced user. Call it what you want - favouritism, arrogance, but actually keeping the site clean is better than being oh so nice to everyone. At some point, you could have that privalage.

Comment: @Tim Yip. Agreed. And he also showed good example some minutes after closing the post to explain why he closed it. By adding all those related duplicate posts I could not find myself. I was just too fast in reacting.

Answer (score 4):

> How could we be more welcoming?

Well, we all try to be, but sometimes our efforts aren't appreciated. Yes, some people are rude to newcomers, but most of us aren't. That doesn't mean users don't have to follow the rules. You can expect us to be nice, but we expect all other users, old or new, to follow the rules the *whole community* makes.

That last point makes that the behavior between sites can differ and that some sites are a little looser following the rules than others. One should learn to adapt if he or she participates in a community (or more of them).